# Search algorithm vector iterator not dereferencable c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator

I've just copied from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/ the algorithm that 'Search' looks for a subsequence.

It looks like that:

```
template<class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2>
  ForwardIterator1 search ( ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                            ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2)
{
  if (first2==last2) return first1;  // specified in C++11

  while (first1!=last1)
  {
    ForwardIterator1 it1 = first1;
    ForwardIterator2 it2 = first2;
    while (*it1==*it2) {    // or: while (pred(*it1,*it2)) for version 2
        if (it2==last2) return first1;
        if (it1==last1) return last1;
        ++it1; ++it2;
    }
    ++first1;
  }
  return last1;
}
```

I've tried to use this algorithm with visual studio but in the end of the debugging it crashes with the following debug error:

> vector iterator not dereferencable

My code that I initiate some vectors is:

```
vector<int> v1 = { 1,4,7,10,5,0};
vector<int>v2 = {10,5,0};
vector<int>::iterator it = cpp_search(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Did you step through the program with a debugger to see where the issue is?

Comment: The code in the condition for the `while` loop dereferences two iterators, then the code tests whether those same iterators are off the end of their respective ranges. That's wrong; if either of the iterators is off the end, it's not dereferenceable.

Comment: You should consider using a better reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search

Comment: Just say "no" to `http://www.cplusplus.com`; it's garbage.

Comment: @PeteBecker So how can one fix the while loop?

Comment: You were given a link to an article that shows a correct implementation. In what way does it fail to satisfy your needs?

Comment: @axcelenator - the fix would be to check the iterators are valid before dereferencing.   Or use the link given by NathanOliver to find a more robust approach.

Comment: @Peter How can I check the iterators for validity?

Comment: make sure they do not equal last